# Create a child page with multiple parent

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I would like to create a navigation in an Angular application where I can access the same page from multiple "parent" page and keep the navigation aware of the page it's coming from.

I'm using the `routerLinkActive="active"` on my navigation. I have two pages (Favorites, All users) that display a list of users. Users have a details page that you can navigate to using `users/userId`.

What I'd like to do is that when the user details link is clicked from the "Favorites" list, the "active" navigation stays on the "Favorites" menu button, and when I click from All users it stays on All users

This is how my routes are currently configured

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'favorites',
  component: FavoritesComponent
},
{
  path: 'all',
  component: AllUsersComponent
},
{
  path: 'user/:id',
  component: UserDetailComponent,
}
```

This is how my routes are currently configured and, obviously, when I navigate to the `user/id` page, neither `favorites` nor `all` is "active" in my navigation bar.

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz code example?

Comment: a nested router-outlet should solve that, but can you be more specific about what you want to accomplish?

Comment: well a simple solution is to  create two separate child routes for the same component  (UserDetailComponent)  and this route  should be added as a child route to  both the parent route `favorites` and `all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse the same component as a child route under each main route, i.e `favorites` and `all`. The key thing here is to define an empty route path that goes to the main component for that route and then create a detail route that will fall under the main route. Your route config should look something like this:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'favorites',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: FavoritesComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'user/:id',
        component: UserDetailComponent,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'all',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: AllUsersComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'user/:id',
        component: UserDetailComponent,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'user/:id',
    component: UserDetailComponent,
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: "/all" }
];
```

With the above configuration the `favorites` and the `all` links will behave as you want.

## [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shared-route-example)

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed what I was looking to do. Now, if the `UserDetailComponent` has child routes (we have tabs on this page), we have to repeat the child routes in all three paths or there is a simpler solution?

Comment: nevermind, your stackblitz code already answers the question, simply using a const to define the `UserDetailComponent` route. Perfect, thanks!